# Is there any way of handling error on establishing connection to SQL Server on application level?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, exception, sqlconnection

I'm talking about this error message that always appears everytime i lose my internet connection or everytime the server becomes offline:

**A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)**

I want to know the best way of displaying a friendly error message for this. Actually, this is what I did:

```
        Try
            Using conn As New SqlConnection(ConnectionStrings("ConnectionName").ConnectionString)
                Dim command As SqlCommand = conn.CreateCommand()
                conn.Open()
                Dim transact As SqlTransaction = conn.BeginTransaction()
                command.Transaction = transact
                Try
        'codes to execute
        transact.commit()
                Catch ex As SqlException
        transact.rollback()
                    'display error
                End Try
            End Using
        Catch ex As SqlException
            'display friendly error message
        End Try
```

I need to do this everytime I use a sqlconnection. Is there a way to make a single block of code that could handle all of the instance of this error on all of my pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the most practical way, I think. Sometimes you'll need to display different error message or different approach even though they have the same exception.

You can also try this article https://web.archive.org/web/20211020134127/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/081209-1.aspx but note that redirection is sometimes not a good option to say that something went wrong in your website especially in a page where user will fill-out a form, you don't want him to lose his progress, do you?

If you are using SqlDataSource http://forums.asp.net/t/978920.aspx/1

Comment: Or you can read this article: http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/081209-1.aspx

Comment: I'm also thinking of exceptions from SqlDataSource. I extensively use SqlDataSource on GridViews and DateilViews, if I'll also code exception handling everytime I use SqlDataSource, that would be too frustrating.

Comment: See this article: http://forums.asp.net/t/978920.aspx/1 They show here how to catch exception of SqlDataSource

Answer (score 1):

If you need to handle your errors on a single block, the best place is the `global.asax Application_Error` method. There you can check the exception through:

```
Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();
```